# Is it possible to use android phone in BLE peripheral role in reality?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, google-contacts-api

My question is on Android capability, whether or not we can use the Android smartphone as a BLE peripheral device. Base on my efforts, the connection will be dropped very quickly and we can't establish a persistent connection in this mode. We are struggling with this issue for two weeks. While Android documentation is mentioning that is possible and Android devices are able to play the peripheral role but this is not happening in reality.

Comment: They can advertise, so yes.  If you're having trouble with the implementation, providing what you've done so far might help.

Comment: As I said we can make the connection (we use another smartphone in the central role) but the connection is not permanent and it will be dropped after a moment by the peripheral phone.

Comment: Do you know any application in the market that plays the peripheral role for Android smartphones?

Comment: Your biggest concern is probably that a lot of phones still have Bluetooth 4.0 chips, which have very hard limitations on different concurrent roles. If any app on the phone works as master, you can't have an app that works as slave at the same time for example.

Comment: @Emil Actually, we are using two smartphones, one as peripheral and another as central, and we can establish the connection but is defective and is not useful.

Comment: Which two devices are you using? You could use a BLE sniffer to see what's going on.